# What term would describe the current form of discourse that involves preaching to the choir while aggressively attacking those that disagree?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am thinking about the current style of public speaking where the speaker addresses many claims and attacks against those who do not agree. All the while pretending to be trying to convince their audience but know full well that their audience is already on board and willing to cheer whatever they say.

Preaching to the choir doesn't capture the negative and aggressive aspects of this rhetorical style.

Comment: Isn't this just _politics_? The 'aggressive' style is captured by the term _polemics_: **polemic**: a piece of writing or a speech in which a person strongly attacks or defends a particular opinion, person, idea, or set of beliefs [[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/polemic)] (I'd make this an answer, but the 'preaching to the choir' constraint is missing.)

Comment: You could call it *Trumpism*, perhaps.

Comment: @Robusto: Or you could call it *populism*. Until about a year ago we just used to call it *democracy*, but the establishment on both sides of the pond are reluctant to accord that term to the political process now they're not so sure of always winning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Whatever you call it, it leaves me feeling like a Christian Scientist with appendicitis. At a time when we need reason and reasonability more than ever, what we get is this.

Comment: @Robusto: Too true. Not that I'd go so far as to *endorse* Trump, but I can't help feeling that questions like this one are often motivated by a desire to dismiss him with pseudo-intellectual put-downs. Most of the liberal media in the UK gave pretty sneering accounts of his recent "campaign-style" rally in Florida, for example, and they'd love to have slipped in something like the target word here (if it exists). Me, I reserve judgement as regards the bigger picture - I'm willing to suppose he's just a man, and simply needed a bit of a break from being constantly attacked from all sides.

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster...

> [**rabble-rouser**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rabble%E2%80%93rouser)
>    *one that stirs up the masses of the people (as to **hatred** or **violence**)* (italics mine)

Comment: No; the 'preaching to the choir' aspect is missing.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Okay - ***populist** rabble-rousing*. But in all honesty, I never heard of rabble-rousing being used in contexts where the rabble weren't more than willing to be roused.

Comment: Hey – I can alter my vote after changing your whotsit to a hyphen. I was negating the upvote, but someone went further, so I've negated the ... oh whotever. But do you really think you'd get away with calling X, Y, and Z 'rabble-rousers'? Polemicists, maybe.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: That "whotsit" was simply the exact text as cut and pasted from the MW link, so I'm not sure why you object to it. Personally I think it's actually the establishment who've been most preoccupied with "button-pressing" emotional appeals over the last year or so, but I admit I probably couldn't get away with calling Clinton, NYT, Cameron, etc. "rabble-rousers". They're actually more interested in sedating the electorate than rousing them.

Comment: I didn't object to it; it came in handy. But I could change it to an ELU hyphen and change the vote.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: If I'm honest, I don't actually think my contribution here *exactly* encapsulates the meaning OP seeks. It all gets a bit murky though, since almost certainly anyone wishing to use the hypothetical *mot juste* here would also wish to imply that the people being attacked by the rabble-rouser are actually "the good guys" (and by further implication, anyone willing to be "roused" against them must be an idiot).

Answer (score 1):

Demagogue: a political leader who seeks support by appealing to popular desires and prejudices rather than by using rational argument. (In ancient Greece and Rome) a leader or orator who espoused the cause of the common people.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, ***playing to the gallery***!

Wiktionary:

> *Verb*
>   **[play to the gallery](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play_to_the_gallery)**
>   (intransitive, idiomatic)
>   To appeal to the least sophisticated parts of an audience in order to obtain
>   maximum approval.

Comment: This addresses one aspect. But 'playing to the gallery' has been addressed here before. This question includes the 'aggressive attack on opponents' theme.